# SAP B1, How to display fetched Image from ItemImage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sapb1

I'm fetching an image from SAP B1 Service Layer.
In postman, I'm able to view it as `image/png`, but there is an issue displaying it.

What's the correct way to show it in `<img />`?

`require(fetchedImage)` - doesn't work

---

I have created a Cloud Function to fetch the image and pass it on to the client, but I am not sure how to do it.

Having a super weird object something like this

```
 data:
>     '�PNGörönöu001aönöu0000öu0000öu0000örIHDRöu0000öu.........
```

Don't know how to pass it via `res.send(IMAGE IN PNG)` so I can see get an image on the client-side.

Checked `base64` conversion but I'm not sure how to use them.

---

### Update

Postman Request: (This is working fine)

> GET : https://su05.consensusintl.net/b1s/v1/ItemImages('test')/$value
>
> **Headers**: SessionId: *ASK ME WHEN YOU TRY*

For some reason, we can't fetch the Image directly in Front-End and need to create a middleware so we're doing it in `Firebase Cloud Function`

So here is the function which fetches the image and doesn't know how to pass it.

Here is the function in Firebase Cloud Function:

```
if (!req.body.productId) {
      res.status(400).send({ error: "productId is required" });
      return;
    }

    console.log("Starting the process");

    const productId = req.body.productId;

    const login = await Auth.login();
    const fetchedImg = await ItemMaster.getImage(login["SessionId"], productId);

    //Here in the fetchedImg, we're getting some data like
    res
      .status(200)
      .set("Content-Type", "image/png")
      .send(fetchedImg);
```

And we're getting a response like this:

> { status: 200,
>
> statusText: 'OK',
>
> headers:
>
> ```
> { server: 'nginx',
>
>   date: 'Wed, 22 Jan 2020 03:52:22 GMT',
>
>   'content-type': 'image/png',
>
>   'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
>
>   connection: 'close',
>
>   dataserviceversion: '3.0',
>
>   'content-disposition': 'inline; filename="rr-96600.png"',
>
>   vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
>
>   'set-cookie': [ 'ROUTEID=.node2; path=/b1s' ] },
> ```
>
> config:
>
> ```
> { url:
> ```
>
> > data:
>
> '�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000�\b\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0006\u001fS�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0019tEXtSoftware\u0000Adobe ImageReadyq�e<\u0000\u0000\u0003hiTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000

THIS IS SUPER LONG AND GOES FOR 80-100 more lines

If you want to test you can use the following:

Postman:

> POST: https://us-central1-rapid-replacement.cloudfunctions.net/getImageFromItems
>
> body: {"productId":"test"}

Valid productId are: 1. "RR000102" 2. "test"  3. "RR000101"

Comment: Have you set the content type in the backend `res.set({'Content-Type': 'image/png'});`

Comment: Yes I tried that as well, it gives a broken image.

Comment: do you save them somewhere?

Comment: No, I'm not, is there a way to get it done without that?

Comment: You can proxy it directly `const request = require('request')` and in the route `request.get(url).pipe(res);`

Comment: it's not a URL, its an image itself, is there a way to get that?

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: Sure let me do that.

Comment: @C.Gochev it's updated sorry for the delay

Comment: I tried many ways but no success. I tried turning the image into a blob on the frontend and using `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` for the src and I also tried sending it as a stream from the api but still it doesn't show . The images always come broken. I am interested if there is a solution to this

Comment: Thank you very much for the time, please post some of your findings as an Answer so I can credit you with an upvote for your time. @C.Gochev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the closest to a working solution I came. Basically what I tried is to fetch the image and then turn it into a blob on the client so you can make it into a `objectURL`.Updated code streams the image as a buffer and consumes it on the client then turns it into objectURL and assigns to image src

Server code:

```
const http = require('http')
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs')
const stream = require('stream')
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/') {


    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    axios.post(
      "https://su05.consensusintl.net/b1s/v1/ItemImages('test')/$value", {
        responseType: "blob"
      }).then(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp.data)
      const buf_stream = new stream.PassThrough()
      buf_stream.end(Buffer.from(resp.data))
      buf_stream.pipe(res.end())
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
})


server.listen(3500)
```

Client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <img style="width:200px; height:200px" />
  <script>

  const img = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")
  fetch('http://localhost:3500').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    return response.body
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    const reader = data.getReader()
     return new ReadableStream({
    start(controller) {
      return pump();
      function pump() {
        return reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
          // When no more data needs to be consumed, close the stream
          if (done) {
              controller.close();
              return;
          }
          // Enqueue the next data chunk into our target stream
          controller.enqueue(value);
          return pump();
        });
      }
    }
  })
})
  .then(stream => new Response(stream))
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  .then(url => img[0].src = url)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey one thing I forgot to tell you, that I do get an image here `GET : https://su05.consensusintl.net/b1s/v1/ItemImages('test')/$value`, but when I pass the same thing, it's not working. Let me know if you get a better idea, sorry if I'm bothering you.

Comment: small appreciation from my side :)

Comment: see updated code. this was my final attempt. hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use images dynamically, you have to fetch the images as soon as the component is mounted and insert it afterwards. The fetched picture should then be saved in the state of the component and included from there in the src attrbut of the img tag. Assuming you can already fetch the picture, the code below should work.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ComponentWithFetchedImage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { image: undefined };   
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let fetch_url = "https://picsum.photos/200";   // Insert your fetch url here
    fetch(fetch_url)
      .then(res => res.blob())
      .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
      .then(url => this.setState({ image: url }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="component">
        <img src={this.state.image} alt="" />
      </div>
    );   
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't fetch directly in ComponentDidMount, as I need to make a custom function on the Server-Side and for that, I'm doing it via Cloud function.

Comment: It's not allowing me to fetch on client side, it says illegal headers passed in fetch / axios, when I do it from React.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved.

```
const getImage = async (sessionId, ItemCode) => {
  console.log("fetching image");
  let result = {};

  result = await axios.get(
    `${settings.url}${endpoints.ItemImages}('${ItemCode}')/$value`,
    { 
      headers: {Cookie: `B1SESSION=${sessionId}`},
      responseType: "arraybuffer" } 
    ).then(response => Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64'));

  //Here we're returning base64 value of Image
  return result;
};
```

So we're able to see the image on the client-side using

> `<img src="data:image/png;base64,[BASE64-VALUE-HERE]"/>`